# How to read an encrypted value from database and compare it with another value in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, encryption, cryptography

Tools used: Visual Studio 2019, ASP.NET Core 5.0, SQL Server 2014

I encrypted a date `(Datetime.Today.AddDays(8))` and successfully saved it into the database.

I tried to decrypt the value with `@Model.Decrypt(Model.Date.DateEnc)` but it doesn't work.

How can I retrieve the encrypted value from the database, decrypt it and compare the decrypted value with the date today?

My Decrypt.cshtml page is:

```
@if(Model.Decrypt(encryptedValue).toString() == Datetime.Today.toString())
{<p>Correct</p>}
else
{<p>Wrong</p>}
```

My Decrypt.cshtml.cs page is:

```
    public string Decrypt(string cipherText)
    {
        string EncryptionKey = " Bt2a";
        cipherText = cipherText.Replace(" ", "+");
        byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x01, 0x22, 0xcc, 0x0e, 0x50, 0x4d, 0x05, 0xa4, 0x4f, 0xff, 0xe3, 0x69, 0x7a });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using MemoryStream ms = new();
            using (CryptoStream cs = new(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }
            cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        }
        return cipherText;
    }
```

Encrypt method:

```
public string Encrypt(string icu)
        {
            string EncryptionKey = "Bt2a";
            byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(icu);
            using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
            {
                Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x01, 0x22, 0xcc, 0x0e, 0x50, 0x4d, 0x05, 0xa4, 0x4f, 0xff, 0xe3, 0x69, 0x7a });
                encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
                encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
                using MemoryStream ms = new();
                using (CryptoStream cs = new(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                icu = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
            }
            return icu;
        }
```

Comment: how is your encrypt method your looks like ?

Comment: The string is too long for a comment here, so i am providing a mega.nz link --- https://mega.nz/file/ANkm3QxR#uktML2EoevKPUTJih6ijpJQ9A2P_hKvlJlUW0kbfCQI

Comment: `string EncryptionKey = " Bt2a";` and `string EncryptionKey = "Bt2a";`... well that ain't right.

Comment: that is my mistake on copy paste, but the key is ok ("Bt2a") on both sides.

Comment: the code you provider works just fine, are you sure you the encrypted value is not altered before or after it is saved to database ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally i managed to solve the problem.

**I had forgotten to declare the constructor "ED = await _context.EncDates.FirstOrDefaultAsync();" inside the Decrypt.cshtml.cs --> OnGetAsync()
and this gave and "null" value when comparing the date strings.**

Thank you for your help.

Below is the full code.

**--- Decrypt.cshtml ---**

```
@if(Model.Decrypt(Model.EncDates.encryptedValue).toString() == Datetime.Today.toString())
```

{

Correct

}
else{

Wrong

}

**--- Decrypt.cshtml.cs ---**

...

```
[BindProperty]
    public EncDate ED { get; set; }
    public IList<EncDate> EDL { get; set; }

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        EDL = await _context.EncDates
            .Include(a => a.Lic).ToListAsync();

        ED = await _context.EncDates.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }

    public string Decrypt(string cipherText)
    {
        string EncryptionKey = "Bt2a";
        cipherText = cipherText.Replace(" ", "+");
        byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x01, 0x22, 0xcc, 0x0e, 0x50, 0x4d, 0x05, 0xa4, 0x4f, 0xff, 0xe3, 0x69, 0x7a });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using MemoryStream ms = new();
            using (CryptoStream cs = new(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }
            cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        }
        return cipherText;
    }
    
    public string Encrypt(string icu)
    {
        string EncryptionKey = "Bt2a";
        byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(icu);
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x01, 0x22, 0xcc, 0x0e, 0x50, 0x4d, 0x05, 0xa4, 0x4f, 0xff, 0xe3, 0x69, 0x7a });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using MemoryStream ms = new();
            using (CryptoStream cs = new(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }
            icu = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
        }
        return icu;
    }
```